# How to use regular expression to use as few groups as possible to match as long string as possible

Tags: regex

For example, this is the regular expression

```
([a]{2,3})
```

This is the string

```
aaaa // 1 match "(aaa)a" but I want "(aa)(aa)"
aaaaa // 2 match "(aaa)(aa)"
aaaaaa // 2 match "(aaa)(aaa)"
```

However, if I change the regular expression

```
([a]{2,3}?)
```

Then the results are

```
aaaa // 2 match "(aa)(aa)"
aaaaa // 2 match "(aa)(aa)a" but I want "(aaa)(aa)"
aaaaaa // 3 match "(aa)(aa)(aa)" but I want "(aaa)(aaa)"
```

My question is that is it possible to use as few groups as possible to match as long string as possible?

Comment: Your examples do not generalize to "use as few groups as possible". The smallest possible number of groups is zero, trivially; the answer is then simply `a*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
(a{3}(?!a(?:[^a]|$))|a{2})
```

This looks for *either* the character `a` three times (not followed by a single `a` and a different character) *or* the character `a` two times.

**Breakdown:**

```
(                   # Start of the capturing group.
    a{3}            # Matches the character 'a' exactly three times.
    (?!             # Start of a negative Lookahead.
        a           # Matches the character 'a' literally.
        (?:         # Start of the non-capturing group.
            [^a]    # Matches any character except for 'a'.
            |       # Alternation (OR).
            $       # Asserts position at the end of the line/string.
        )           # End of the non-capturing group.
    )               # End of the negative Lookahead.
    |               # Alternation (OR).
    a{2}            # Matches the character 'a' exactly two times.
)                   # End of the capturing group.
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qIkLCO/4).

Note that if you don't need the capturing group, you can actually use the whole match instead by converting the capturing group into a non-capturing one:

```
(?:a{3}(?!a(?:[^a]|$))|a{2})
```

[Which would look like this](https://regex101.com/r/qIkLCO/3).

Comment: This seems to be the right answer. Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: On it actually.

Comment: @Joshua I just made a slight change to the pattern because I found a flaw in it, that is, it didn't work properly when the extra `a` is at the end of the line. Please use the updated version.

Comment: I just notice the same thing when I was trying it in Python. I thought I got something wrong in my code. The new one works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex:

```
^(?:(a{3})*|(a{2,3})*)$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CTTiKn/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `(?:(a{3})*|(a{2,3})*)` - a non-capturing group containing 2 sub-sequences separated by OR operator

  - `(a{3})*` - The first subsequence tries to match 3 occurrences of `a`. The * at the end allows this subsequence to match 0 or 3 or 6 or 9.... occurrences of `a` before the end of the line
  - `|` - OR
  - `(a{2,3})*` - matches 2 to 3 occurrences of `a`, as many as possible. The * at the end would repeat it 0+ times before the end of the line

-`$` - asserts the end of the line

Comment: This fails for any number of `a` above 6. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/sufPq4/1).

Comment: Then just add `+` after the closing parenthesis. This is actually probably the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this short regex:

`a{2,3}(?!a([^a]|$))`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/KpDoin/4)

**How it's made:**

I started with this simple regex: `a{2}a?`. It looks for 2 consecutive `a's` that may be followed by another `a`. If the 2 `a's` *are* followed by another `a`, it matches all three `a's`.

This worked for most cases:

[image]

However, it failed in cases like:

[image]

So now, I knew I had to modify my regex in such a way that it would match the third `a` only if the third `a` is not followed by `a([^a]|$)`. So now, my regex looked like `a{2}a?(?!a([^a]|$))`, and it worked for all cases. Then I just simplified it to `a{2,3}(?!a([^a]|$))`.

That's it.

[image]

**EDIT**

If you want the capturing behavior, then add parenthesis around the regex, like:

`(a{2,3}(?!a([^a]|$)))`

Comment: Rather than simply explaining how a regex is working, I prefer to explain how it's made (my thought process, kind-of). I guess, it's easier to understand how the regex is working once you know how it was made.

Comment: This does not seems to work on all character. For example, I replace `a` with `=`. It does not work on `====`.

Comment: The accepted answer also matches `a`'s only. That's why I guessed that you needed to match `a`'s only.

Comment: No, the accepted answer actually accepts other characters.

Comment: Woops, my bad. I'll modify it if I can, otherwise, I will delete the answer. Thanks

Comment: @Joshua Try this a{2,3}(?!a([^a]|$))